# Make sure float is less than double C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

Here's what I want to do:

> Take a double (which is between -1 and 1) and cast it to a float. But I want to make sure that the float is ALWAYS less than the double.

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

For reference, here's something I came up with.

```
float DoubleToSmallerFloat (double X) // ex. X = 0.79828470019999997
{
    float  Y = X; // 0.79828471 -> note this is greater than X

    double Diff = X - Y;
    return Y - Abs (Diff) * 10;
}
```

Comment: What are you going to do when the `double`'s value cannot be represented as a `float`?

Comment: What do you mean? The double can be casted to a float

Comment: No, not always. The range of a double is greater than that of a float. What will you do when the double has a value that's too small to be represented by a float?

Comment: There is issue with range of double, which is larger. When `double` is in range of `float`, then it would be possible.

Comment: Typically a double is twice the size of a float which gives it a bigger range of numbers it can store.  This means you could store a number in it that you cannot store in a float.  How do you want to handle that case?

Comment: I've edited by question. Im only concerned with doubles between -1 and 1

Comment: @nathanesau What is the actual high-level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: A matrix of doubles has a determinant > 0. The same matrix using floats has a determinant < 0. The determinant needs to be > 0. This should be the case if each float <= double

Comment: Bigger in this case doesn't just mean larger numbers. A `double` can handle much smaller fractions as well. so -0.0000000000000001 as a `double` may be represented as 0 in a `float`, resulting in a number that is larger than the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is a good question. Look at IEEE 754 single-precision and double-precision binary floating-point format

[image: IEEE 754].

[image: Double]

The real value assumed by a given 32 bit binary32 data with a given biased sign *s*, exponent *e* (the 8 bit unsigned integer), and a 23 bit fraction (mantissa) is

```
s * m * (2 ^(e-127)),
```

where *m* is

[image]

For double use 1023 instead of 127: `s * m * (2 ^(e-1023))`

**First case** is exponent *e* and sign *s* save its values after double-float cast. Then float mantissa is almost first digits of the double mantissa. You need to slightly decrease the value of float mantissa.

**Second case**. Exponent (e-127) from float is greater than exponent (e-1023) from double. Then I hope that fraction part is 23 zeros. Ok. Decrease exponent part and set fraction part to 23 ones. To get access for the fields use union.

```
union {
    float    fl;
    uint32_t dw;
} f;
int s = ( f.dw >> 31 ) ? -1 : 1;   /* sign */
int e = ( f.dw >> 23 ) & 0xFF;     /* exponent */
int fract = f.dw & 0x7FFFFF;       /* fraction */
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are able to use C++11 then you can use [`nextafter()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) for this:

```
float doubleToSmallerFloat(double x) {
    float f = x;
    return f < x ? f : nextafter(f, -1.0f);
}
```